# ObjectDisposedException even after setting client handler to false so I'm not disposing and using the same instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

From reading other posts on stackoverflow, I'm trying to reuse the same httpclient for multiple methods but i'm still getting the error:

`System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.`

```cs
public class Program
{
    private readonly static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    private readonly static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, false);

    public Program()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }


    public async IDictionary<string, object> GetCustomer(string customerId)
    {
        using (client)
        {
            try
            {
                 var response = await client.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                 var responseContent = await.result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>(responseContent);
            }
            catch { }
        }

    }

    public async IDictionary<string, object> GetOrdersByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        using (client)
        {
            try
            {
                 var response = await client.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                 var responseContent = await.result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>(responseContent);
            }
            catch { }
        }

    }
}
```

In a separate file, I'm calling these two methods one right after the other as such:

```
var customer = programInstance.GetCustomer().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var orders = programInstance.GetOrdersByCustomerId().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When I call `GetCustomer()`, the response is 200 OK and I'm able to retrieve the information I want but as soon as I call `GetOrdersByCustomerId()`, I then get the error message stated earlier.

I've been reading about whether httpclient needs to be dispose or how some people got rid of the error by grabbing the handler and setting dispose to false but it doesn't look like it's working out for me.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: If you're trying to reuse it, don't dispose of it until you're done with it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it seems that the part i don't understand. how do i not dispose of it?

Comment: Don't use `using (client)` ? Do you know what that statement does? If not, perhaps we should try to cover that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that both your methods are disposing your `HttpClient` making it unusable in further calls, like any disposed object (Streams, ...)

You either want to instantiate a new `HttpClient` each time, if used inside `using` (not a good idea according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) if high load is expected), or keep the instance until the application shuts down.

Comment: okay, i believe i understand the instantiating a new client each time but how do i keep the same instance if i wanted to? could you explain a bit more on how to do that?

Comment: Your `HttpClientHandler` and `HttpClient` instances are already static variables in your Program class, which means they will be there as long as the program is running. Simply leaving out the `using(...)` statement should be everything that is needed.